# Remove phrase from HTTP_REFERER url in php

Tags: php, url, referer

I need to use the previous url of the current page but remove specific phrases.

In order to get the previous url i used the http_referer function like so:

```
$previousurl = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

from the end of that url i need to remove the phrases "?view=listcats", "?view=listcats-2"

i tried the following but with no luck:

```
$previousurlfull = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$phrase = array("?view=listcats", "?view=listcats-2");
$previousurl = str_replace($phrase, "", $previousurlfull);
```

Thank you in advance for the help!!!!

Comment: Try using the [`parse_url`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.

Answer (score 5):

The best way to do this is with [parse_url](http://us.php.net/parse_url) for the HTTP_REFERER and then [parse_str](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) for the query string, of course it's better if you do some kind of validation so you can handle errors.

UPDATED EXAMPLE // this is a far more complicated example but gives you full control.

```
$previousurlfull = 'http://stackoverflow.com/?view=listcats&sup=1&test=true';
$clean_link = parse_url($previousurlfull);
parse_str($clean_link['query'], $args);

// validation need
$link = $clean_link['scheme'].'://'.$clean_link['host'].$clean_link['path'];

$link .= '?'; // add ? to the beggining 

// use Iterator so you can use hasNext
$iterator = new CachingIterator(new ArrayIterator($args));

foreach($iterator as $k => $v){

    // if doesnt have the view query key
    if($k != 'view'){
            $link .= $k.'='.$v; // insert the key and value

            if($iterator->hasNext()){
                $link .= '&'; // if it has another item on the array insert &
            }
    }
}

echo $link;
// output = http://stackoverflow.com/?sup=1&test=true
```

Working example: [example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/yyuCkD)

---

OLD EXAMPLE;

```
 $previousurlfull = 'http://stackoverflow.com/?view=listcats&sup=1&test=true';
 $clean_link = parse_url($previousurlfull); // Parse URL
 parse_str($clean_link['query'], $args); // Parse Query String to an array

 echo '<pre>'; // clean output

 var_dump($clean_link);

 echo $clean_link['scheme'].'://'.$clean_link['host'].$clean_link['path'];

 var_dump($args);

 echo $args['test'];
```

Output

```
 array(4) {
  ["scheme"]=>
  string(4) "http"
  ["host"]=>
  string(17) "stackoverflow.com"
  ["path"]=>
  string(1) "/"
  ["query"]=>
  string(29) "view=listcats&sup=1&test=true"
}

echo $clean_link['scheme'].'://'.$clean_link['host'].$clean_link['path']; // example

// $args Query Output
array(3) {
  ["view"]=>
  string(8) "listcats"
  ["sup"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["test"]=>
  string(4) "true"
}
```

working example: [example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/5tmEzh)

Comment: This is probably the way it should be handled, but you should give an example to demonstrate how to put the array back together for a full url for the user.

Comment: Yes, but should be included here.  Also, the example doesn't include the path.

Comment: Though that would be straight forward, getting the array and do some simple concatenation :), but just edited it! thx

Comment: What if I want to keep all the GET params but not `view=listcats`?
What If I want to keep `&view=listcats` but not `?view=listcats`?

Comment: How do you figure it doesn't work with that URL?  The User never said they wanted to keep `test=true`. On top of that, you can further breakdown the query part of the URL from this rather than possibly breaking the entire URL with a simple string replacement. Also, you can filter it based on the url, as a google referrer would be useful to keep the query because it contains the searched key terms, while a local referrer would be almost useless in needing to know the query string from.

Comment: OP didn't say he needs an URL without params. He said "*from the end of that url i need to remove the phrases "?view=listcats", "?view=listcats-2"*"

Comment: Then explode the query at `&`, to break down the variables if you need them. According to OP's comment on a different answer - you are correct, but that just makes it a bad question - or incorrectly asked question.  With this particular one, it should be about multiple string replacement rather than handling the `HTTP_REFERRER`

Comment: Just updated my anwser, you can use parse_str to strip your query.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do it as:

```
$previousurl = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$new_url=explode("?",$previousurl);
echo $new_url[0];
```

Comment: Seems to be a better approach in this scenario.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing of the above works. I will try to be more specific. 

I have a table that all the rows are being filed like so: 

    <?php
    $previousurl= $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    ?>
    
    <ul>
     <li><a href="<? echo $previousurl; ?>/search-by/area?value=state">State</a></li>
    </ul>

In some occasions the previous urls include phrases such as "?view=listcats", "?view=listcats-2" 

So i need to remove only those specific phrases and not all phrases after the "?"

Hope that helps a bit. Thank you all for the answers so far!

Answer (score 0):

```
$phrases = array("?view=listcats", "?view=listcats-2");
$replace = array('', '');
$previousurl = str_replace($phrases, $replace, $previousurlfull);
```

Comment: There are a few things wrong with this, the main being that the example doesn't work, `$phrase` is never defined.  Also, limiting to except only two possible `query`'s is bad form, and will eventually break if not constantly updated for what other referrers may be passed to the page with different query values.

Comment: Oh well the first is a typo, I mainly copied from a guys answer but wanted to show that you don't need `foreach`. OP asked to explicitly remove those 2 strings so what?

Comment: This site isn't means for specific scenarios, and such a well-defined scope.  Answers are meant to help others that come across the site at any time looking for similar issues - you answer won't help with that as the scope is too narrow.  Also, just because someone has an idea for how they were doing something doesn't mean it is the correct way to do it; answers should show the correct way, rather than just changing the empty string to an array of empty strings.

Comment: If this site is not about specific problems, why do we have 100000000000 duplicate "how to get PHP variable with ajax" noob questions? Look at the other answers here,.. there is no common solution because the problem is specific.

Comment: And look at the users that asked many of those questions.  Most of them are new users and don't know how to search effectively - that doesn't diminish the ability to provide a good answer that can help out others that are looking for something similar.  Instead of getting offended, understand that there are better ways to approach a problem rather than how the user was attempting to solve it - getting offended and sticking to a way that isn't how a problem should be approached isn't going to help anyone.